# How to retrieve User details from SessionID using RESTful APIs?

Tags: java, rest, authentication, web-applications

I have developed a web application in which the user logins through third party authentication. Now, I want to retrieve the User details i.e. UserID, Username etc. through the session and based on User details, different roles will be assigned to different users. Third Party is ready to share the sessionID and through which they want me to retrieve this information using RESTful APIs.

What changes i need to make in my code in order to do so?

Comment: I think sharing the name of the third party's name would not be bad. Also, show us please what you already tried.

Comment: Where do you want to retrieve these details? Are you the client? If yes, there is no direct way. The server will have to provide a resource to GET the session details.

Comment: @Tichodroma -  I want to retrieve these details in my application so that if the user logins through third party authentication, he/she automatically lands on overview page and specific role is automatically is assigned to that user. I am not the client but I need to make these changes and they will provide me details about the session but I don't know how to retrieve those details and then use them

Comment: @ArthurEirich - Is name of the third party really matters?? and I haven't done anything much till now. Still reading about RESTful APIs and how to use them